# Error while installing module odoo: module loading failed

Tags: python, git, python-2.7, odoo

I have developped this module but I can not run it, i keep getting this error track and no idea what it is, thanks in adcance.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Utilisateur\git\persol\odoo\openerp\http.py", line 405, in response_wrap
response = f(*args, **kw)
File "C:\Users\Utilisateur\git\persol\odoo\addons\web\controllers\main.py", line 948, in call_button
action = self._call_kw(model, method, args, {})
File "C:\Users\Utilisateur\git\persol\odoo\addons\web\controllers\main.py", line 936, in _call_kw
return getattr(request.registry.get(model), method)(request.cr, request.uid, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Utilisateur\git\persol\odoo\openerp\api.py", line 268, in wrapper
return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Utilisateur\git\persol\odoo\openerp\addons\base\module\module.py", line 447, in button_immediate_install
return self._button_immediate_function(cr, uid, ids, self.button_install, context=context)
File "C:\Users\Utilisateur\git\persol\odoo\openerp\api.py", line 268, in wrapper
return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Utilisateur\git\persol\odoo\openerp\addons\base\module\module.py", line 495, in _button_immediate_function
registry = openerp.modules.registry.RegistryManager.new(cr.dbname, update_module=True)
File "C:\Users\Utilisateur\git\persol\odoo\openerp\modules\registry.py", line 370, in new
openerp.modules.load_modules(registry._db, force_demo, status, update_module)
File "C:\Users\Utilisateur\git\persol\odoo\openerp\modules\loading.py", line 355, in load_modules
loaded_modules, update_module)
File "C:\Users\Utilisateur\git\persol\odoo\openerp\modules\loading.py", line 255, in load_marked_modules
loaded, processed = load_module_graph(cr, graph, progressdict, report=report, skip_modules=loaded_modules, perform_checks=perform_checks)
File "C:\Users\Utilisateur\git\persol\odoo\openerp\modules\loading.py", line 176, in load_module_graph
_load_data(cr, module_name, idref, mode, kind='data')
File "C:\Users\Utilisateur\git\persol\odoo\openerp\modules\loading.py", line 118, in _load_data
tools.convert_file(cr, module_name, filename, idref, mode, noupdate, kind, report)
File "C:\Users\Utilisateur\git\persol\odoo\openerp\tools\convert.py", line 894, in convert_file
convert_csv_import(cr, module, pathname, fp.read(), idref, mode, noupdate)
File "C:\Users\Utilisateur\git\persol\odoo\openerp\tools\convert.py", line 962, in convert_csv_import
raise Exception(_('Module loading %s failed: file %s could not be processed:\n %s') % (module, fname, warning_msg))
Exception: Module loading mgmtsystem_dysfunction failed: file mgmtsystem_dysfunction\security/ir.model.access.csv could not be processed:
Line 1 : id,"name","model_id
```

Comment: id,"name","model_id is a syntax error. either remove double quotes or balance them. a quote is missing

Comment: I never used dquotes for column names and never had issues. Try one of both: remove dquotes, or balance them appropriately.

Comment: That totally solved my problem thanks !!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the error in the last line, tells:

```
Line 1 : id,"name","model_id
```

This is because the CSV file is ill-formed. Go to such file (indicated one line above as: `mgmtsystem_dysfunction\security/ir.model.access.csv`) and either balance the double quotes (the last one is missing) or remove them.